# D3 (v4): update pattern multiple elements in group

Tags: d3.js

I have a chart with multiple `g` elements that contain a `circle` and a `text` element.

I use the following code:

```
  var nodes = [{"oe": 1, "name": 'test'},{"oe": 1, "name": 'test2'},{"oe": 0, "name": 'test3'}]

  //join 
  var nodeGroups = d3.select('g.maingroup').selectAll('g.nodegroup').data(nodes);

  //enter
  var nodeGroupsEnter = nodeGroups.enter().append('g').attr("class", "nodegroup");      
  nodeGroupsEnter.append("circle");              
  nodeGroupsEnter.append("text");

  //update
  nodeGroups.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 4)
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return ((d.oe) ? " oe" : "");
    });

  nodeGroups.select("text")
    .text(function (d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "top")
    .attr("y", 10)
    .attr("dy", -15);    

  //exit
  nodeGroups.exit().remove();
```

All the `g` elements are drawn, however both the `circle` and `text` elements are empty, the attributes do not seem to be added properly during the update fase. Any ideas on why this is?

*note*: I am using v4 of d3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually this seems to working (just added and `svg` element and centered the nodes)

*Edit*

For v4 you need to [merge](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_merge) selections, see below:

```js
var nodes = [{
  "oe": 1,
  "name": 'test'
}, {
  "oe": 1,
  "name": 'test2'
}, {
  "oe": 0,
  "name": 'test3'
}]

//join 
var nodeGroups = d3.select('svg').append('g')
 .attr('transform', 'translate(50, 50)')
 .selectAll('g.nodegroup').data(nodes);

//enter
var nodeGroupsEnter = nodeGroups.enter().append('g').attr("class", "nodegroup");

nodeGroupsEnter.append("circle");
nodeGroupsEnter.append("text");

//update
nodeGroups.merge(nodeGroupsEnter).select("circle")
  .attr("r", 4)
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    return ((d.oe) ? " oe" : "");
  });

nodeGroups.merge(nodeGroupsEnter).select("text")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  })
  .attr("text-anchor", "top")
  .attr("y", 10)
  .attr("dy", -15);

//exit
nodeGroups.exit().remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.8.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="100" height="100"></svg>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention I am using version 4 of d3 and there it doesn't work.

Comment: If you add the `merge` to the text element as well, it works indeed :) `nodeGroups.merge(nodeGroupsEnter).select("text")` THANKS

Comment: @Christian-G updated my answer to reflect this as well